# If Ethereum switch to POS,how do/should I prepare the mining machine?

Tags: mining

Sir,
   We are developing a application using Ethereum. For now,we use test environment.But in the future,We will  build up a private chain for formal environment. If Ethereum switch to POS from POW,how do I build the mining machine? I am afraid that if I prepare mining machines now,these machine will be useless when Ethereum switch to POS.

How do I plan the infrastructure?
   Thanks!
             Barkely

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main public Ethereum chain currently uses Proof of Work (mining). The details of Ethereum's Proof of Stake implementation have not yet been finalized, so it's not yet possible to describe exactly what you will need to "mine" it, but it will probably require a machine with good security, good uptime and a reliable network connection.

However, this probably isn't relevant to you: If you are running a private chain, you are not limited to the system being used by the main public Ethereum chain. Proof of Work is usually unsuitable for private chains, because the cumulative hashpower of the participants is likely to be low, so it would be easy for a single participant to turn on a lot more hashpower and take over the chain. Proof of Stake may well be unsuitable as well.

For private networks with known participants it is often better to use a Proof of Authority system. There is [an implementation in Parity](https://github.com/paritytech/parity/wiki/Demo-PoA-tutorial), and one is currently under development for [Geth](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/geth). There are also other systems like [ErisDB](https://monax.io/platform/db/) that use the Ethereum Virtual Machine, so code you write for the public Ethereum chain will also work with those.